# unable to set UILabelView.Text value

Tags: swift, xcode, forced-unwrapping

I'm getting this error and unable to resolve it...

I'm passing an object from UIViewController to another through a UISegmentedControl button changes. Below is the code I'm using to pass the object. It is working great and I'm able to print the object details in the console.

```
 @IBAction func switchViewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let vc = DirectionsViewController()
        if let unwrappedRecipe = self.details
        {
            vc.customInit(recipes: unwrappedRecipe)
        } else

        {
            print("it has no value!")
        }
        self.viewContainer.bringSubviewToFront(views[sender.selectedSegmentIndex])

    }
```

However, the issue is when I'm trying to set a value to a label, I get the below error:

```
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Below is the code I'm using inside DirectionsViewController

```
 @IBOutlet weak var lblDirections: UILabel!
var recipe: Recipe? = nil

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func customInit(recipes: Recipe)
{
    lblDirections.text =  recipes.name
}
```

I have researched about optional & forced variables, also tried to safely unwrap variables but with no luck. Can someone help pls?

Comment: It’s probably becausw you didn’t connect the lblDirections outlet to the label in the viewcontroller.

Comment: @P.vanderLaan its connected already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `IBOutlet` that is load from storyboard or xib, it is `nil` until `viewDidLoad` is called. So when `func customInit(recipes: Recipe)` is called before `viewDidLoad`, the `lblDirections` is `nil`, and because it is force unwrapped it will crash. You can fix this in a two way:

1. Ugly but easy. The `viewDidLoad` is called when you first get `view` of a view controller, so you can add `_ = vc.view` just before `vc.customInit(recipes: unwrappedRecipe)` in `func switchViewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)`. I'm not recommending using it production code, but you can use to test if everything is working fine.
2. Because you are using xib, you can initialize a view controller and provide custom init (even name of your method indicates it: `customInit`). To have a proper view controller init you need to use:

```swift
class DirectionsViewController: UIViewController {
   let recipe: Recipe
   @IBOutlet weak var lblDirections: UILabel!

   init(recipe: Recipe) {
       self.recipe = recipe
       let classType = type(of: self)
       let bundle = Bundle(for:classType)
       super.init(nibName: "DirectionsViewController", bundle: bundle) //provide your nib filename 
   }

   override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //code from func customInit(recipes: Recipe)
       lblDirections.text =  recipe.name
   }

   @available(*, unavailable, message: "use init(recipe: Recipe)")
   override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
       fatalError("init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) has not been implemented")
   }

   @available(*, unavailable, message: "don't use sotryboard! use nib and init(recipe: Recipe)")
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}
```

You can't provide optional `Recipe` or update it after creating, but it makes code less complicated. It also assumes that your xib file is called `DirectionsViewController.xib` (if not you need to change it in line `super.init(nibName: "DirectionsViewController", bundle: bundle)`).

---

You can also use my micro-library [NibBased](https://github.com/MaciejGad/NibBased) to have a little less code to write. When using the library your code should be:

```swift
import NibBased

class DirectionsViewController: NibBaseViewController {
    let recipe: Recipe
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDirections: UILabel!

    init(recipe: Recipe) {
        self.recipe = recipe
        super.init()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblDirections.text =  recipe.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After analyzing your answer and fiddling with the code. I have managed to solve the problem. The init method was a life saver. ☺️ I have passed the recipe object in the initialisations `views.append(DirectionsViewController(recipe: self.details!).view)
`

Comment: I think you should also keep a reference to a view controller as a whole, not only its view. You can read more about it here: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/child-view-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value to the recipe variable in the DirectionsViewController and in the viewDidLoad method of DirectionsViewController call

```
    lblDirections.text =  recipe.name
```